# How could we access the multiple dict in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list which contains multiple dict and all the dict have same key but different values. I want to get a dict which has maximum value for a particular key.

```
l = [{'a':23, 'b': 64, 'c':4},{'a':83, 'b': 34, 'c':47}]
```

I want to get a dict which has maximum value for 'b'.

Comment: insert mandatory disclaimer about not using `list` and other builtins  for variable names here, use some other name. It overshadows the list builtin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `max` with a custom key:

```
>>> l = [{'a':23, 'b': 64, 'c':4},{'a':83, 'b': 34, 'c':47}]
>>> max(l, key=lambda x: x["b"])
{'a': 23, 'b': 64, 'c': 4}
```